# razor html.raw with an array using jquery showing the entire array

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Want to use @Html.Raw to display the string of Html decode.

I am displaying messages based on the tab that's being click on. Everything works correctly when I do not use @Html.Raw. Without @Html.Raw I get one message with @Html.Raw I get all 3 messages. I am using jquery to control what is being displayed.

How do I get 1 message to display using @Html.Raw so that the Html decode will display.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdZzP.jpg)

**Control logic to build the array**

```
 customerVM.DisplayMessage = new[] { company.Tab_Footer_WebOrder_Message, company.Tab_Footer_Order_Message, company.Tab_Footer_Invoice_Message };
```

**Html**
@Html.Raw(@Model.DisplayMessage[i]) should only display 1 message based on the tab being click.

```
<div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.DisplayMessage.Length; i++)
    {
     <p style="@(i == 0 ? "" : "display: none;")" id="tab-description-@(i + 1)" class="tab-description">@Html.Raw(@Model.DisplayMessage[i])</p>
    }
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#tabs").tabs({

    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        var getTab = $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href");

        $(".tab-description").hide();

        switch (getTab) {
            case "#tabs-1":
                $("#tab-description-1").show();
                break;
            case "#tabs-2":
                $("#tab-description-2").show();
                break;
            case "#tabs-3":
                $("#tab-description-3").show();
                break;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the html.raw helper interpret the type of the object.
try to create an intermediate variable

```
<div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.DisplayMessage.Length; i++)
    {
       var tmp=@Model.DisplayMessage[i];
     <p style="@(i == 0 ? "" : "display: none;")" id="tab-description-@(i + 1)" class="tab-description">@Html.Raw(tmp)</p>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove the Html.Raw.  I get the results I am looking for.  But removing the Html.Raw does not display the Html decode.